# How do I properly implement a drop down menu with just CSS?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm struggling with an issue with my drop-down menu, which is that the dropdown menu is displayed properly, but disappears once it stretches below the containing div. Here's an illustration of what i'm talking about:

[image: dropdown menu]

The menu only extends to the height of the black containing `<div>`. Here's my framework:

```
<ul>
     <li><a href=''>Menu Item</a></li>
     <li><a href=''>Menu Item 2</a>
     <ul class="sub_menu">
          <li><a href=''>...</a></li>
          <li><a href=''>...</a></li>
          <li><a href=''>...</a></li>
     </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: It would help if you would put up what you have on jsFiddle.

Comment: @Brian Hoover http://jsfiddle.net/ankurt/Cx2xL/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try giving your containing element an `overflow` property of `visible`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify the width and height properties for your ul, and li elements yet ?